What happened to Vyasa at the end of Mahabharata?
When Vrishnis slaughtered each other and Dwarka submerged in the ocean, Arjuna went to Vyasa's asylum. He was sad. Vyasa told him that it is high time to leave this material world.
Mahabharata 16.8

By thee also, O foremost of men, with Bhima for thy helpmate and the twins, O mighty-armed hero, has the great work of the gods been accomplished. O foremost one of Kuru's race, I regard thee and thy brothers as crowned with success, for ye have accomplished the great purpose of your lives. The time has come for your departure from the world.

Following Vyasa's instruction, Pandavas left Hastinapur and visited a few tirthas and eventually went to heaven.
Mahabharata 17.1

Ascertaining the resolution of Arjuna, Bhimasena and the twins fully endorsed the words that Arjuna had said. Resolved to retire from the world for earning merit, they brought Yuyutsu before them.


"'The five brothers, with Draupadi forming the sixth, and a dog forming the seventh, set out on their journey. Indeed, even thus did king Yudhishthira depart, himself the head of a party of seven, from the city named after the elephant. The citizens and the ladies of the royal household followed them for some distance.

However, what happened to Vyasa? When did he die?

Related Do the eight immortals (Including Lord Hanuman) still exist in Kaliyuga?…Sage Krishna Dvaipayana is one of the immortals, he is current Vyasa and will be in saptrishis of next manvantara..

There is no reference to Vyasa ever dying. Vyasa was alive even at the time of Janamejaya -

Hearing that Janamejaya was installed in the snake-sacrifice, the
learned Rishi Krishna-Dvaipayana went thither on the occasion. And he,
the grand-father of the Pandavas, was born in an island of the Yamuna,
of the virgin Kali by Sakti’s son, Parasara. And the illustrious one
developed by his will alone his body as soon as he was born, and
mastered the Vedas with their branches, and all the histories.


Section LX, Adivansavatarana Parva, Mahabharata.


Is he immortal?
